Type realized by $n$-tuple (Chang & Keisler)
I am studying model theory using the third edition of "Model Theory" by Chang and Keisler. On page $8$ they write (paraphrasing):
$``$Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas in the (free) variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and let $\mathscr{U}$ be a model for $\mathscr{L}$. We say that $\mathscr{U}$ $\textit{realizes}$ (satisfies) $\Sigma$ iff some $n$-tuple of elements of the domain of $\mathscr{U}$ satisfies $\Sigma$ in $\mathscr{U}$. $\Sigma$ is consistent iff $\Sigma$ is satisfiable in some model.$"$
On the same page they write (again paraphrasing):
$``$By a $\textit{type}$ $\Gamma(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ in the variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ we mean a maximal consistent set of formulas of $\mathscr{L}$ in these variables. Given any model $\mathscr{U}$ and $n$-tuple $a_1, \dots, a_n$ of the domain of $\mathscr{U}$, the set of all formulas $\gamma(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ satisfied by $a_1, \dots, a_n$ is a type.$"$
What I'm finding difficult to see is how the set of all formulas $\gamma(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ above is maximal. This does not seem immediate to me. Let's call this set $tp_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \dots, a_n)$. I'm interpreting the above as saying that
$$tp_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \dots, a_n) = \left\{ \gamma(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mid \mathscr{U} \models \gamma(a_1/x_1, \dots, a_n/x_n) \right\},$$
where $\gamma(a_1/x_1, \dots, a_n/x_n)$ is the formula obtained by replacing each $x_i$ in $\gamma(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ by $a_i$. While this is certainly a consistent set of formulas, why is it that adding another (distinct) formula makes it inconsistent? It is not clear to me that no model could satisfy all formulas in $tp_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and some additional ones with free variables in $x_1, \dots x_n$. Have I misunderstood some definition?

Please don't change a_i/x_i to fractions. They are not fractions, and this is standard notation for variable substitution.

This is essentially because formulas can be negated. You can take that as a hint and try to write the proof yourself, or continue reading.
Let $\gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be any formula that is not in $\operatorname{tp}_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Then by definition $\mathscr{U} \not \models \gamma(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, and hence $\mathscr{U} \models \neg \gamma(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Once again, by the definition of the type we have $\neg \gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \operatorname{tp}_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Therefore $\gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is not consistent with $\operatorname{tp}_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.
The contrapositive of the above is the statement that whenever $\gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is consistent with $\operatorname{tp}_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$  then $\gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \operatorname{tp}_\mathscr{U}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. Maximality then follows.

That's almost embarassingly simple. Thank you very much!

+1 especially for the first sentence. When a logic doesn't have negation, it's important to remember that quite a few of the things we "know" aren't true any more.
